# Randomly generated dungeon with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to create a completely random maze/dungeon for a small text game I'm working on. I'm really not sure where to start since I've never done anything like this before. How do I do this? I need the rooms to know what mobs it holds, what items are on the ground, where the exits are and what other rooms they go to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is a pretty broad question. You might not get your answer. I suggest you to incapsulate your data into classes. But first define how you want to represent your world.

Comment: Basically a room right now will just have a name, description, items, and mobs. I want to figure out a way to create a random 'maze' of rooms, some connected, some not. And it's gonna need to remember which exits go where. I know it's broad but I don't have any idea how to simplify it.

Comment: What have you worked out so far? Do you have a functional single-room game yet? It sounds like you haven't worked out even the basics of creating objects and defining their interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an 2 dimentional int array (your map). Each "object" such as an item or exit gets another number.
for example:

```
0 = no object
1 = knife
2 = sword
3 = helm
```

When you need to make it posible to combine objects on one field (for example put an sword and an helm on one field) you can create an 3d array. So you can add an object on top of another object.

You can generate and random x and y whitin your array dimentions and give this an random number within your object scope (in this example between -1 and 4)

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that I could just to a 2d grid but that may not be the case. Would I not be able to just append the items in a room to a list?

Comment: You could have lists for items, lists for monsters, traps, or whatever else you want in the room. For instance you could have an item list and append each item to the list if you want multiple items in a room. Your function would just need to read through the list to determine what times are in a room.

Comment: That is also an option. but i see the the question has been answered, thumbs up :-D

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a very broad question I will just give you a general answer. You are probably going to want to make a new class that will contain the data for a room. In this class you could have variable that could store randomly generated numbers (using the random module) and then have methods use those numbers to determine the layout, monsters, and items in each room. All you would then have to do is to have a 2D or 3D grid (probably using lists of the room class) and randomly fill the grid with rooms that each contain random data.

Comment: I'll take this. It's early and I just threw this up to see if I could get something to make it click. I'll take some time to make a working build and after that I'll be able to be clearer. Thank you!